# How to use categories in the URL with Advanced Custom Fields?

Tags: plugins, categories, advanced-custom-fields

Using the Advanced custom fields plugin:

1) I want to post to the ACF and use a category just like a regular blog post, but the URL would be: `mysite.com/customPost/category/post-name`

Is this possible?  And how can I do it?

2) Can I add a custom page template to each category page?

Answer (score 0):

For #1, I think what you're looking to do is add [Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) and [Custom Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies), which isn't possible via Advanced Custom Fields alone. Custom taxonomies are your own versions of either categories or tags.

If you want to use a plugin to create the post types and taxonomies, you could use something like [Custom Post Type UI](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/). That would get you where you need to go with the URLs.

For #2, yes, you can have custom templates for each category (aka taxonomy) archive page. You could use taxonomy-your-category-name.php to achieve that. See the [full hierarchy list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display) for more details.

You could use these in conjunction with ACF, as well.